# Согласование сказуемого с подлежащими

Tags: согласование

В каком числе лучше поставить сказуемое в следующем предложении?
Шли дни, цветов становилось всё меньше, зато начала(-и) поспевать полевая клубника на краю пустыря и малина в небольшом овражке.

Comment: S, привет! Что это вы решили принять мой вопрос? Как у вас дела, радует ли форум? Почему редко отвечаете?

Comment: Привет, S!  Умным стал за два года здесь :)  Перечитал ответы -- аргументы в пользу мн. числа убедили. Форум радует всегда, а вот отвечать -- то ли лень, то ли ещё что...

Comment: Прекрасно, что радует, а то я сомневалась почему-то. Даже решила зайти, посмотреть, как дела. Уж очень много нулевых вопросов, на которые никто и не собирался отвечать.  Да и обсуждать их не стали – неинтересно или непонятно. А мне они показались любопытными, так что пришлось подумать.

Comment: Видела ваш комментарий к вопросу  о шкатулке. Что за мечты о будущем? Каких именно правил вам не хватает? Может быть, общей темы одного абзаца, которую можно отнести к начальной фразе "Он прикоснулся к шкатулке"? Ставим, к примеру,  после нее многоточие.  А потом авторская пунктуация без запятой при обозначении последовательности действий. Можно использовать двоеточие и объединить предложения в пары точкой с запятой, но это не так красиво.

Comment: Там, конечно, я бы везде поставил запятые. А вариант с общей темой мне нравится. Двоеточие в таком тексте, да, некрасиво.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Правилах согласования сказуемого с однородными подлежащими  рассматриваются факторы, которые могут повлиять на решение, но в конечном итоге каждый вариант решается **индивидуально.** И вот в этом предложении я бы использовала **форму мн. числа для сказуемого:**

*Шли дни, цветов становилось всё меньше, зато **начали поспевать** полевая клубника на краю пустыря и малина в небольшом овражке.*

Все дело **в распространенности**  подлежащих, которые имеют зависимые слова.

Если использовать ед. число, то предложение по мере его прочтения может быть понято некорректно: *Шли дни, цветов становилось всё меньше, зато начала поспевать полевая клубника на краю пустыря...*  А вот следующая далее информация о малине воспринимается как неожиданное присоединение. Такой ситуации можно избежать, **если сразу задать  мн. число сказуемому.**

Для сравнения: *Шли дни, цветов становилось всё меньше, зато **начала** поспевать полевая клубника и малина.* В этом предложение сказуемое стоит в форме ед. числа

Answer (score 2):

Корректно ед. ч.

Шли дни, цветов становилось всё меньше, зато начала поспевать полевая клубника на краю пустыря и малина в небольшом овражке.

Здесь действуют два фактора.

> Если однородные подлежащие связаны соединительными союзами **и, да или только интонацией,** то действуют правило: при прямом порядке слов (сказуемое следует за однородными подлежащими) обычно употребляется форма множественного числа сказуемого, **при обратном порядке (сказуемое предшествует подлежащим) – форма единственного числа.**

Форма единственного числа сказуемого предпочитается при смысловой близости однородных подлежащих, например:

> 1)      сказуемое предшествует подлежащим: **На стене висела винтовка и высокая казацкая шапка (Пушкин); В нем [Пушкине], как будто в лексиконе, заключалось все богатство, сила и гибкость нашего языка (Гоголь); Главной заботой была кухня и обед (Гончаров); И с берега, сквозь шум машины, неслось рокотание и гул (Короленко).

[Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П. Справочник по правописанию, произношению, литературному редалтированию](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_08)

Answer (score 0):

НачалИ

Думаю, если поставить подлежащее и сказуемое в прямом порядке и без второстепенных членов, то станет понятнее: полевая клубника и малина начали поспевать. (Аналогично, например, "Маша и Петя пошлИ собирать грибы")